# What encryption mode should I use to protect CAN bus communication?

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a [CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) project and I should encrypt the communication between nodes using the AES algorithm. Which encryption mode should I use?

Comment: Do you want to use this within the CAN  protocol? If not and this should be the case, then you should provide more information about your system, entities, attack models, risks, etc.

Comment: Also, do you have a reliable way to keep track of a counter across messages with any given key (ie can you use a counter for a nonce without it EVER repeating before you re-key) or not? That would change my answer between AES-GCM and AES-GCM-SIV. Anything less secure needs more info to recommend it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "needs more details". Without more information about your constraints, we can't give you any advice. We can _guess_ that you want lightweight, but that's about all. You could certainly use GCM. If you have hardware-accelerated AES instructions, then it's possible that CCM would actually be faster. And how are you going to generate the nonce?

Comment: I need to provide confidentiality and authentication because of sniffing attacks and messages injection so i will encrypt data among nodes . That's all

Comment: Many have told me i should use aes-gcm , but i want to know why this one ?

Comment: @PeterKamel It's secure and authenticated, so unlike CBC or CTR, it's not malleable.

Answer (score 3):

Theory aside, there's basically no way to have security on the CAN bus.

The Controller Area Network, or CAN bus, is a differential bus that is robust enough for critical communications but simple enough to be used with micro-controllers. CAN bus employs a message-based protocol over four wires, power, ground, CAN-, and CAN+, where the message from a device with the lowest ID becomes dominant on the bus.  In the language of the CAN specification, the “dominate” bit is “0” and “recessive” bit is “1” based on the fact the signal lines are drive to their high and low states by transistors in the dominate state and that resistors passively pull the signal lines to each other in a passive fashion in the recessive state. Relating to physical security of this bus, if you "short" two lines, it will cease to function.

CAN data frame starts with an arbitration field that contains the ID of the node. If two nodes have a message at the same time, both nodes will start transmission concurrently, and the node with the higher ID number in binary will stop transmitting when it sets the bus to be recessive, which is a “1”, but detects that the bus is in a dominate state, which is a “0”. At this point, a collision has happened and the node has lost arbitration. This is also the physical reason that it is impossible to physically protect the CAN bus from a malicious device on the bus, because setting the bus to “0” that forces the bus into the dominate state is an attack on availability, such as a DoS attack. The best that the system can do in this case is to detect the fault and shut down.

[image]

Security for CAN bus through authentication protocols for CAN bus proves difficult because authentication codes are not tied to message IDs, which makes them impossible to trace, and do not generally seem appropriate for implementations on simple microcontrollers. Although authentication is required and is an important problem, you will have to focus only on **encryption of the data** in the CAN frame because of its importance from the hardware implementation perspective.

You cannot use a counter because you cannot guarantee delivery of a packet.  You are pretty much stuck with ECB mode for encryption.

Comment: What about using a 256-bit block-sized cipher that sign-and-enc in one block?

Comment: @kelalaka Depends on the version. With standard CAN, you only have up to 8 bytes in the payload.  With Extended CAN, you can have up to 64-bytes.  Most automotive stuff use standard CAN, but I'm sure that Tesla has something.  I hear that if you don't get your repairs blessed by the factory you get a brick-mobile.

Comment: I see, even the 8-byte with DES one can design, however, that won't be secure against who of cource.

Comment: Some go deeper https://www.instructables.com/Exploring-the-Tesla-Model-S-CAN-Bus/

Comment: This is a great insight into the CAN bus protocol, but you could certainly do encryption of the payload. Hell, you could even send IP over CAN if you really wanted, although it would be horribly inefficient, error-prone, slow, and in all ways inferior to anything like IEEE 802.3 (Ethernet). You also _can_ guarantee delivery if you have a protocol underneath it which supports that, much like TCP/IP provides certain guarantees to IP regarding the delivery of messages, even though IP itself does not have that.

Comment: To echo what forest said, you can put whatever you want in the data packet. You'll need to send multiple data packets for most block ciphers, and 2 data packets for a 128-bit authentication tag, but you can "easily" run whatever protocol you want wrapped in the CAN packets.

Comment: You cannot really assume that the data flows two directions.  Having used these basic systems, I don't think it's feasible.

Comment: @bdegnan Well it certainly would benefit from bidirectional communication for effective cryptography, but even that is not an absolute necessity, depending on how you encrypt the contents.

Comment: and this is why I'm not a cryptographer. :P

Comment: @bdegnan  I wonder whether the bit stuffing (for synchronization) would problematize encryption.  Having six consecutive bits of the same polarity is considered an error in the fields with bit stuffing, which includes the data field.

Comment: @Patriot the biggest issue would be distributing keys, particularly because things don't always talk back, such as brakes.  I really don't know.  There's just a lot in that bus that make this hard.

Comment: Presumably they're manufacturing both ends, so a pre-shared key could work. No good way to have forward secrecy if you can't do new exchanges, but static keys can be better than nothing.